# Simple.Data and Sql Azure Transient fault handling

Tags: azure, simple.data

One of the things in my todo list is to download and grok the Simple.Data's Github code one day, but until then I was wondering if the framework already handles the Transient faults (by retry logic or otherwise) as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680927(v=pandp.50).aspx when working with a SqlAzure database. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not, but that is an excellent point and I shall add it to the roadmap for v2. I'll update this answer with the version number when it is done.